# blackberry web works plugin is not downloading from http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web?

Tags: blackberry, web, blackberry-webworks

I am new to BlackBerry Web Works.I am trying to create blackberry web works application using eclipse ide.For that I am trying to install it from "Help->Install New Software" in eclipse using http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web this link.But its not able to start download in eclipse version other than 3.6 and 3.7.

Again I have downloaded 3.7 eclipse .Still I am facing the same type problem and unable to download it.

Is there any solution to this problem or I have to use procedure given on development site?

Please help me to figure out this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually Blackberry doesn't support any more and you have to follow the procedure given on development site:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html